# How can I insert a string into existing string?

Tags: sql, oracle

The data in my table looks like this:

```
       COL1 
row 1  aa aa a.bb bb bb.
row 2  aa a   aa  aa  a  a. bb bb bbb bb.
row 3  aa a   aaa   aa  aa  a  a. bbbbb bb  bb bbb bb.
row N  aa a   aaa  aaa a  a aa  aa  a  a. bbbbb bb  bb bb bb bbb bb.
```

How can I add a fixed string value before the first full stop/period in the existing column string value? I need the result to look like this:

```
       COL1
row 1  aa aa a(substring).bb bb bb.
row 2  aa a   aa  aa  a  a(substring). bb bb bbb bb.
row 3  aa a   aaa   aa  aa  a  a(substring). bbbbb bb  bb bbb bb.
row N  aa a   aaa  aaa a  a aa  aa  a  a(substring). bbbbb bb  bb bb bb bbb bb.
```

Comment: Please make clear how your table looks like, preferably as a create table x as select statement, or at least with clear column names. Then, please add expected output.

Comment: Are you only changing `a.`, where `a` is a fixed value; or the first period that appears in the string regardless of what (if anything) comes before and after it?

Comment: fixed value - this first point and second point.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using explicit string operations:

```
select substr(col, 1, n) || string || substr(col, n+1)
```

As a side note:  This functionality is available in other databases:

- `stuff()` (in SQL Server)
- `insert()` (MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression, with [the `regexp_replace()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions149.htm):

```
regexp_replace(col1, '\.', '(substring).', 1, 1)
```

e.g.:

```
select regexp_replace('aa a   aaa   aa  aa  a  a. bbbbb bb  bb bbb bb.',
  '\.', '(substring).', 1, 1)
from dual;

REGEXP_REPLACE('AAAAAAAAAAAA.BBBBBBBBBBBBBB.','\.','(SUBST
----------------------------------------------------------
aa a   aaa   aa  aa  a  a(substring). bbbbb bb  bb bbb bb.
```

Or if you only want to match `a.`, include `a` in the pattern and replacement string:

```
regexp_replace(col1, 'a\.', 'a(substring).', 1, 1)
```

With all your sample data via a CTE:

```
with t (id, col1) as (
  select 1, 'aa aa a.bb bb bb.' from dual
  union all select 2, 'aa a   aa  aa  a  a. bb bb bbb bb.' from dual
  union all select 3, 'aa a   aaa   aa  aa  a  a. bbbbb bb  bb bbb bb.' from dual
  union all select 4, 'aa a   aaa  aaa a  a aa  aa  a  a. bbbbb bb  bb bb bb bbb bb.' from dual
)
select id, regexp_replace(col1, 'a\.', 'a(substring).', 1, 1) as col1
from t;

ID COL1                                                                   
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 aa aa a(substring).bb bb bb.                                            
 2 aa a   aa  aa  a  a(substring). bb bb bbb bb.                           
 3 aa a   aaa   aa  aa  a  a(substring). bbbbb bb  bb bbb bb.              
 4 aa a   aaa  aaa a  a aa  aa  a  a(substring). bbbbb bb  bb bb bb bbb bb.
```

If you want to modify all appearances of `a.` then adjust or remove the occurrence and position arguments.

You can use the same thing as part of an update if that is what you require.

Comment: The string is the explanatory variables on.
Number of rows - too variable.

Comment: @VitalieBancu - I'm sorry, I really don't understand what you mean. Your examples all have a single insertion. Either of these patterns will change the original data you showed to the result you showed.

Comment: Thanks. Now works.

regexp_replace(col1, '\.', '(substring).', 1, 1) -- Good solution.